# Setup netcoreapp2.2 Test with Test Agent 2017 on a TFS Build Agent

Tags: tfs, .net-core, vstest

I try to get my build working with that uses a "Visual Studio Test" Task to execute tests in a testproject.

This task executes the following line:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" D:\S\4\s\test\Project.Test\bin\release\netcoreapp2.2\Project.Test.dll /Settings:D:\S\_temp\1b091bf0-fe0a-11e8-996b-6798074e2821.runsettings /EnableCodeCover age /logger:trx "/TestAdapterPath:`"D:\S\4\s`""
```

The problem is, that if I call this line on my dev machine with VS2017 installed, tests get executed and everything works fine.
If I call it on the Build server with VS Build Tools 2017 and VS Test Agent 2017 installed, it runs into a timeout and a dotnet.exe process crashes with the following message.

[image: dotnet.exe crash message]
_

```
 dotnet test .\test\Project.Test\bin\release\netcoreapp2.2\Project.Test.dll
```

works well on both machines.

Did I do anything wrong, or is this a Bug?

*All VS/VSTestAgent/VSBuildTools are of version 15.9.4 and .Net Core 2.2 SDK is installed.*

Comment: net471 test projects are also working on the same build server. It's just a netcore 2.2 issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add a runsettings file like advised by mayankbansal018 [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1869#issuecomment-446888321) then everything works fine.